# What are some practical advantages of storing a country code rather than just the country name itself?

Tags: php, country-codes

I apologize in advance if this is a newb question, but what are some practical advantages for doing this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Country code is the same for every language but country NAME is not the same in every language.**

Comment: +1 this is definitely the main reason. Plus country names can differ even in the *same* language - think "Democratic republic of..." vs. the pure country name.

Comment: It helps localisation of the country names, indeed.

Comment: baller answer man :-D good job.

Comment: and everyone else, thx for taking time out to reply to this thread.  Just to go a step further, should I be using 2 or 3 character ISO codes?

Answer (score 2):

Country codes are much shorter and take up less storage/memory.

Answer (score 1):

Country Code is unique and it's usefull for db-search